# How does solr group by query(group.query) work internally?

Tags: performance, solr

I am trying to achieve grouping according to the fields matched in a single query. So in the group.query parameter I am passing individual queries according to field names and in the query parameter, I am passing just the search term to be matched against the default copy fields. However It is taking too much time compared to querying individual fields separately and combining the data at my end.

here is the sample query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/psqlTest/select?q=201*&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.query=road_name:201*&group.query=own_name:201*&group.query=tel_no:201*&group.query=assm_no:201*&group.limit=5
```

This query takes time in order of seconds to complete when atleast 100 users are hitting(using jmeter).

The query over each fields and joining the results take time in order of 100-200 ms for the same jmeter parameters.
Why is there such a huge difference in the performance?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/lucene/grouping/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh Can you tell why groupby is utilizing more cpu and more time compared to querying each field separately?

Comment: No, I'm not that familiar with the details of the grouping functionality. You could try using the streaming expressions functionality to see if that gives you better results.